# tutorials for the basic's of understanding android development

Tags: android

I'm now 3 months into android development and done quite a lot tutorials now. I've build a lot of small Apps according to these tutorials, the most of them give you the method writen and done, tell what they do and tell where to put them. However, now I am into my own Apps I notice that I'm having trouble understanding how the methods actually are build.
for example:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void arg) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        if (mStatusCode  == 200){
            mTwitterUser = new TwitterUser(mResultString);
            updateView();
        }
        else if (mStatusCode  == 404){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "De gevraagde gebruiker bestaat niet.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mTwitterUser = null;
            updateView();
        }
        else if (mStatusCode > 0){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Er is in verbindingsfout opgetreden met foutcode " + mStatusCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mTwitterUser = null;
            updateView();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Gegevens konden niet worden opgehaald. Controleer uw internetverbinding en probeer het opnieuw (" +mConnectionException.toString() + ")" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mTwitterUser = null;
            updateView();
        }
    }
}
```

}

(some dutch error text in the toast)
this is an example of a tutorial that explained really well what everything does but doesn't really zoom in on things like, what does @override, what is protected/void, what is NULL or when to use it, etcetera. As you can see, very easy BASIC stuff which is crucial for understanding java/android coding.

So, are there any tutorials out there that are really for understanding and zooming into method building and basic android coding?

thanks in advance,~olijf

Comment: Its a **Core Java Concepts**. Refers any Java Basic tutorials.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for basic java tutorials? Perhaps a good java book would be a god start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these.....

**-** First to be a real good coder in android, i mean the Good ones, please try to improve you Java SE. You can use `Head First Java` book for grasping these fundas, you can also move to other books after that like Thinking in Java.

**-** Second an easy step by step methodology is used to teach android in `Head First Android` book.

**-** See this below links for tutorial by Marakana and newboston channel which will help u in understanding the Android step by step:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5RHtKIo_KDI&feature=relmfu

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUOWNXGRc6g

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, Mark Murphy book [The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development](http://commonsware.com/Android/) is the best one to start with. Then you can proceed with his [book about advanced Android development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/098167805X). His books differ because he not only explains all the elements but also the concepts behind decisions and main Android principles in general. So, in the end you can answer not only how you can achieve some functionality but also why you should do it this way.

Obviously, official documentation at [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/develop/index.html) site helps a lot too. They have pretty good guides and training.